# How to use SetModelState in a C++ to enable and disable gravity of an object

Tags: ros, gazebo, c++

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear All.
I want to use a c++ program to enable and disable gravity of an object.Who can give a bit help? Gazebo Ros
How to use SetModelState in a C++ to enable and disable gravity of an object

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30400/how-to-use-setmodelstate-in-a-c++-to-enable-and-disable-gravity-of-an-object/) by [zhenli](https://answers.ros.org/users/1716/zhenli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 287 on 2012-03-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In case someone comes across this question and wants an answer, check this out - http://answers.ros.org/question/12116/calling-gazebo-service-set_model_state-in-c-code/

---

Originally posted by [devesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/4103/devesh/) with karma: 104 on 2013-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TouchDeeper](https://answers.ros.org/users/39695/touchdeeper/) on 2020-07-25**:
but the answer link you post has no content about how to disable gravity.